# Can't Hear Visual studio C# Audio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, audio, visual-studio-2019, console-application

So I'm trying to code this random UI thing for practice, and I want to play an mp3 file, but can't seem to actually hear the file. Yes, I have speakers, and yes they work. The file seems to be playing, but doesn't produce any audio output on my computer. I couldn't seem to find another post or question that was answered that actually helped.

It may be a hardware issue and not the code, I'm not sure though

```
class Program
    {
    string keyChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello,[user]!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Username");
            Console.WriteLine();
            
            string uname = Console.ReadLine();

            Thread.Sleep(600);
            Console.Clear();
            Thread.Sleep(600);

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Axiom, " + uname);
            Console.WriteLine("If You Want To Find The Full List Of Commands, Please Press 1");
            Console.WriteLine();

        while (true)
        {

            string keyChoice = Console.ReadLine();
           
            switch (keyChoice)
            {
                case "1":
                    Thread.Sleep(600);
                    Console.Clear();
                    Thread.Sleep(600);
                    Console.WriteLine("Console Commands:");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press '2' To Get 1000$ FREE");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press '3' To Pick Command 3");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press '0' To Exit Or Press A Command Button To Execute A Command");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    continue; 

                case "2":
                    Thread.Sleep(600);
                    Console.Clear();
                    Thread.Sleep(600);
                    Console.WriteLine("Get Messed Up");
                    WindowsMediaPlayer myplayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
                    myplayer.URL = "C:\\Users\\truale\\Desktop\\RickRoll";
                    myplayer.controls.play();
                    //This is where I want to add the file. To rickroll someone of course
                    continue; 

                case "3":
                    Thread.Sleep(600);
                    Console.Clear();
                    Thread.Sleep(600);
                    Console.WriteLine("You Chose Command 3");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press '0' To Exit Or Press A Command Button To Execute A Command");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    continue;

                case "0":
                    Thread.Sleep(600);
                    Console.Clear();
                    Thread.Sleep(600);
                    return;

                default:
                    Thread.Sleep(600);
                    Console.Clear();
                    Thread.Sleep(600);
                    Console.WriteLine("Input Not Valid");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press '0' To Exit Or Press A Command Button To Execute A Command");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    continue;
```

Comment: Where is _Visual Studio_ in your question?  The title is "Can't Hear Visual studio C# Audio"

Comment: Your URL seems to be missing the extension, e.g .mp3 or .wav -- or the file itself. Right now it's just a path to a folder.

Comment: Use something like BASS.NET.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the file path.

We have to add extension like .mp3 or the file's own extension such as:

```
myplayer.URL = "C:\\Users\\truale\\Desktop\\RickRoll.mp3";
```